# Preventing Wix from installing All Features in my Product?

Tags: windows, installation, wix, wix3.5

After installing a MSP patch, Windows Installer decides to install ALL Features provided in the initial MSI. How can i prevent MSP patch from installing All available Features?

Features requests show like this:

```
Installed: Absent
Request: local
Action : local
```

Why is it requesting to install all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the ADDLOCAL property was being set to all the Uninstalled Features. This caused a "Request: local" for each one. What i did to solve the issue was to use a small custom action that deletes this property. It needs to go before CostFinalize because the features to be installed need to be defined before that action.
The variable REINSTALL holds the features that are already installed, and all of them are requested for REINSTALL. So the MSP patch only REINSTALLs the already installed features and leaves the uninstalled features untouched.

```
<CustomAction Id="REMOVE_ADDLOCAL_PROPERTY"
       Property="ADDLOCAL" Value="[NonExistentProperty]"
/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="REMOVE_ADDLOCAL_PROPERTY" Before="CostFinalize">
        <![CDATA[PATCH]]>
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

EDIT:
In the end, this solution worked for one of my patches, but failed for another. So the final solution i've implemented so far is to set REINSTALL=ALL during the Patch.[This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) stands that:

> Note that even if REINSTALL is set to ALL, only those features that were already installed previously are reinstalled. Thus, if REINSTALL is set for a product that is yet to be installed, no installation action will take place at all.

so i think this is a better solution than removing the `ADDLOCAL` property. And also it worked for both patches.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem. Adding REINSTALL=ALL worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the selected features to the registry upon initial installation, `ADDLOCAL` property. When installing the patch, it has to read the states from the registry setup `ADDLOCAL` property accordingly.

Otherwise the patch runs as if the defaults are selected, and therefore the missing features get installed.

<sub>You linked to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327513/wix-upgrade-preselect-features) for Upgrade case, `MigrateFeatures` attribute, which refers to [`MigrateFeatureStates` action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), does not work in case of patches.</sub>

Comment: First, thanks for answering. I can't modifiy the initial MSI because it is a RTM version. The users have already installed this MSi, so i have to build an MSP patch to apply some minor changes. I don't think is really necessary to save in the registry the state of features. I haven't seen any post about saving Feature states. I think there must be a way to tell the MSP patch to ignore features that are not installed.