# ADDLOCAL property getting set during a PATCH

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

I have an MSI package which installs many features that the user can select for installing in his computer. I also have an MSP patch package that updates some components and fixes some bugs in the application. I noticed that during the Patch installation, the property ADDLOCAL gets automatically set to a list containing all the features(during CostFinalize action).

I'd like to know why the "CostFinalize" action is setting ADDLOCAL property and why is it setting it with all the "absent" features.

My problem is that the Patch is installing EVERYTHING.
I really can't find an explanation to this so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Link to same issue: [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/patching-new-component-causes-addlocal-get-set-help-37009292.html)

Answer (score 1):

You already tried to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12288780/572834). That time, you found out that `REINSTALL` property holds the features which were installed by the user.

Then the simple trick of assigning this value to `ADDLOCAL` should help:

```
<CustomAction Id="CopyReinstallToADDLOCAL"
       Property="ADDLOCAL" Value="[REINSTALL]"
/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RCopyReinstallToADDLOCAL" Before="CostFinalize">
        <![CDATA[PATCH]]>
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: The problem is similar but not the same. That fix does not work this time because the CostFinalize action is setting the ADDLOCAL property by his own means. There is no way i can change the ADDLOCAL property here because no matter what i do, the CostFinalize action always sets it to what it wants. There must be an explanation for why the patch tries to Install everything, but i can't seem to find it.  I added a link with a person with the same problem.

Comment: In the [linked example](http://us.generation-nt.com/patching-new-component-causes-addlocal-get-set-help-37009292.html): the patch adds a new component which is part of both the installed feature and non-installed one. That may be the reason why `CostFinalize` thinks it has to install both features.

Comment: Before I saw Alexey's answer, I was going to use Type 1 custom action. His approach worked great. It worked for subsequent patches.